# My htaccess is not working in 000webhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|woff|eot|img|css|js|resources|robots\.txt)   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is the .htaccess file I was using with Codeigniter on 000webhost and it was working perfectly fine.

I have now updated every file but the same .htaccess isn't working.

I am now getting "500 Internal Server Error". 
What might be the problem?

My URL is [futsal-groove.net16.net/home](http://futsal-groove.net16.net/home).

Comment: Try to remove your `.htaccess`than try to access your application.

Comment: Do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: removing htaccess gives 404 error.
and there are no other rules ..

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using?

Comment: Checks: make sure if your using CI3 check file names and class names have first letter upper case.

Comment: Is this htaccess inside root folder?

Comment: yes. it is inside public_html folder.

Comment: Are you getting 404 or 500 error? I just visited your site ,it redirected me to 404 page of 000webhost,

Comment: the above htaccess gets 500 internal server error.
while htaccess provided by you and other gets to 404 error

Answer (score 1):

Some installations requires different approach in solving this issue. It could be either up to PHP version, apache version or something else. On some php installations it's necessary to add a question-mark in the .htaccess file after index.php Try these solutions:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /
# If fuel is not a level up
# RewriteBase /public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# Notice the ? after index.php
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
# Notice the fact that the slash has been removed after the ?

#Other possible setups:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
# Notice the leading slash added before index.php
```

Found it [here](http://fuelphp.com/docs/installation/troubleshooting.html#/404_install).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

[CodeIgniter URLs .htaccess in codeigniter.com](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=urls#removing-the-index-php-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @Nabin when is that you are getting 404??

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess file should be placed on the main directory

```
application
system
.htaccess
index.php
```

Try this code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

On your config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: didnt work either.. 
Well i am now confused whether its htaccess file that is throwing this error.
What else might occur this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a RewriteBase directive or use absolue path in your Rewrite target

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Note : 000webhost server uses virtual user home directory, so it's important to add a RewriteBase directive when are using a relative path in Rewrite target, otherwise you will get a 404 not found.

Source :

https://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=16

Answer (score 0):

Change your htaccess code with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```